# Tensorflow: Efficiently solve Ax=b with constraint x >= 0

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow

One component of a computational algorithm that I am moving from C++ to Tensorflow iteratively computes the solution to Ax=b subject to x>=0 with the following iterative method (in python pseudo-code):

```
for t in range(64):
    for i in range(N):
        x[i] = b[i]
        for j in range(N):
            if i != j: 
                x[i] -= A[i,j] * x[j]
        x[i] = max(x[i] / A[i,i], 0)
```

For the given domain (A strongly positive definite, b positive), the iteration converges quickly with good results.

A naive translation to Tensorflow like the following:

```
for _ in range(64):
    X.assign(maximum(B - einsum('ij,j->i', Azerodiag, X), 0.0) / Adiag)
```

is equivalent to:

```
for t in range(64):
    for i in range(N):
        xp[i] = b[i]
        for j in range(N):
            if i != j: 
                xp[i] -= A[i,j] * x[j]
        xp[i] = max(xp[i] / A[i,i], 0)
    for i in range(N):
        x[i] = xp[i]
```

Unfortunately, these methods do not converge because the iteration needs the latest value of all the x's when computing a new x[i].

Inverting the matrix almost works (closer to correct), but doesn't take into account the constraint x>=0 so produces erroneous solutions for some inputs.

What is the best way to tackle this in Tensorflow? I'd be perfectly satisfied to be able to do the same computations as the C++ version, but I do not see how to do that efficiently with the Tensorflow operators.

It is very fast in the current C++ implementation even though you are looping 64 times because N ~ 64 and this competes very favorably with other methods even without any type of early stopping based on convergence.

The computation is just part of a forward computation as part of a larger graph, so invoking session.run multiple times just to solve this part is not feasible performance-wise.

Comment: would the tensorflow-example in https://github.com/PatWie/CppNumericalSolvers help?

Comment: If you have a working code with loops, where only nnumpy arrays are involved Numba is the way to go. It is very easy to use and speeds up the computation by a factor of 100-1000. So you can do most things quite C-like if apropriate. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49011917/4045774

Comment: Are you still interested in the solution?