# Applying a multi-dimensional function over multi-dimensional array (Python, Numpy)

Tags: python, numpy, apply, dimensions

I have a question how to efficiently apply a function which takes an m-dimensional slice of a n-dimensional array as an input.

For example, I have a n-dimensional array of shape (i,j,k,l). And on the dimensions (j,l), I want to apply the function, which gives me back a matrix of shape (j,l). The resulting numpy array should again have the shape (i,j,k,l).

For example I want to apply the following, normalisation function

```
def norm(arr2d):
   return arr2d - np.mean(arr2d)
```

over the array

```
arrnd = np.arange(2*3*4*5).reshape(2,3,4,5)                    # Shape is (2,3,4,5)
```

on the slice (j,l).

The result I want to achieve I would get via a (slow?) Python list comprehension and moving axes.

```
result = np.asarray([ [ f(arrnd[:,j,:,l]) for l in range(5) ] for j in range(3)])   # Shape is (3,5,2,4) 
result = np.moveaxis(np.moveaxis(result,2,0),2,3).shape                             # Shape is (2,3,4,5) again
```

Is there any better, more "numpyic" way to achieve this, without any involved loops?

I alreay looked at `np.apply_along_axis()` and `np.apply_over_axes()` but the former only works for 1-d functions, and the latter might only work, if my function is implemented as a ufunc.

The example I provided is just a toy example. The solution should work for any python function.

((If normalising a slice would be my specific problem, I could have circumenvented the python loop and moveaxis by using the `ufunc`'s `axes=(..)`.))

Comment: Is `norm(arr2d)` your actual use-case or a toy example?

Comment: This function is a toy example. It should work for any python function. If I would need to normalise over slices like that, I would use something like ``np.mean(arrnd, axis = (1,2))``

Comment: The `apply` functions don't speed things up - they are just convenient (sometimes) ways of iterating.  As long as your function has to be called with scalars or arrays of limited dimension, you have to iterate over the other axes (even if it is hidden by some numpy utility function).

Comment: Maybe numba's guvectorize function fits your bill?

Comment: If you wan't to avoid looping because of performance and not because of shorter code, you can compile your functions.Examples: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49011917/4045774 https://stackoverflow.com/a/49321971/4045774