# numpy.product vs numpy.prod vs ndarray.prod

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm reading through the Numpy docs, and it appears that the functions `np.prod(...)`, `np.product(...)` and the `ndarray` method `a.prod(...)` are all equivalent.

Is there a preferred version to use, both in terms of style/readability and performance? Are there different situations where different versions are preferable? If not, why are there three separate but very similar ways to perform the same operation?

Comment: That's Zen of NumPy.  "There should be three-- and preferably more than three -- non-obvious ways to do it."

Comment: Except, if it's an alias, they do more than just rename the function. `prod` returns `return _methods._prod(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out, **kwargs)` while `product` returns `return um.multiply.reduce(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out, **kwargs)` but they're both in the `fromnumeric` module. It's not so simple to see how it's equivalent...

Comment: @roganjosh I don't follow... in every case, it looks to me like `umath.multiply.reduce` ends up being called.

Comment: @miradulo yeah, I followed it back and you're correct

Comment: @miradulo actually, this seems to have changed quite a bit between my numpy version (1.13.1) and master. It's clearer now in the source that they are the same thing, I was comparing apples and oranges in some senses by looking at the source in my editor and online

Comment: Be careful if performance is really relevant. Depending on your usecase there may be better (and also easy to use) methods: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49321971/4045774

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As of the master branch today (1.15.0), `np.product` just uses `np.prod`, and may be deprecated eventually. See [MAINT: Remove duplicate implementation for aliased functions. #10653](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/10653).

And `np.prod` and `ndarray.prod` both end up calling `umath.multiply.reduce`, so there is really no difference between them, besides the fact that the free functions can accept array-*like* types (like Python lists) in addition to NumPy arrays.

Prior to this, like in NumPy 1.14.2, the documentation claimed `np.product` and `np.prod` were the same, but there were bugs because of the duplicated implementation that Parag mentions. i.e. Eric Weiser's example from [#10651](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/10651):

> ```
> >>> class CanProd(object):
>         def prod(self, axis, dtype, out): return "prod"  
> >>> np.product(CanProd())
> <__main__.CanProd object at 0x0000023BAF7B29E8>
> >>> np.prod(CanProd())
> 'prod'
> ```

So in short, now they're the same, and favor `np.prod` over `np.product` since the latter is an alias that may be deprecated.

Comment: Something to add; regardless of the alias, it's usually slightly faster to call the method on the array object. `arr = np.random.randint(1, 100, size=10000)` --> `timeit np.prod(arr)` of `10.3 µs ± 27.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)`. `%timeit arr.prod()` of `9.58 µs ± 18.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)`

Answer (score 5):

This is what I could gather from the source codes of **NumPy 1.14.0**. For the answer relevant to the current Master branch (NumPy 1.15.0), see the answer of miradulo.

- For an `ndarray`, `prod()` and `product()` are equivalent.
- For an `ndarray`, `prod()` and `product()` will both call `um.multiply.reduce()`.
- If the object type is not `ndarray` but it still has a `prod` method, then `prod()` will return `prod(axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out, **kwargs)` whereas `product` will try to use `um.multiply.reduce`.
- If the object is not an `ndarray` and it does not have a `prod` method, then it will behave as `product()`.
- The `ndarray.prod()` is equivalent to `prod()`.

I am not sure about the latter part of your question regarding preference and readability.