# Map numpy array to mesh

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

Data has been stored in a numpy.array with 3 indices (which correspond to spatial coordinates). To pass it to some python module, the data array needs to be reorganized (and reshaped) to correspond to an array of coordinates, e.g. there should only be one index which corresponds to a 3d (spatial) vector. I got it to work, but it is painfully slow (and I will likely have an array size of 100^3 and not 10^3 like in the MWE). Heres the MWE for which I would like to get suggestions on how to speed things up (significantly), if possible:

```
import numpy as np
import random

# Create regular coordinates
n = 10
minval = -1
maxval = 1
x = y = z = np.linspace(minval, maxval, n+1)

# Create shuffled coordinate array
mesh = np.meshgrid(x, y, z)
coords = list(zip(*(dim.flat for dim in mesh)))
random.shuffle(coords)
coords = np.array(coords)

# Create data
data = np.zeros((n+1, n+1, n+1))
for i in range(n+1):
    for j in range(n+1):
        for k in range(n+1):
            data[i, j, k] = x[i]-2*y[j]+3*z[k]**3

# Reorganize data to correspond to shuffled coordinate array
data2 = np.zeros(coords.shape[0],)
for i in range(n+1):
    for j in range(n+1):
        for k in range(n+1):
            coord = np.array([x[i], y[j], z[k]])
            idx = [np.isclose(coord, xx).all() for xx in coords].index(True)
            data2[idx] = data[i, j, k]
```

Comment: And you are trying to optimize `# Reorganize data to correspond to shuffled coordinate array` part only?

Comment: Yes thats what needs to be optimized.

Comment: Get rid of all lists and list comprehensions and compile your code using Numba. This should give a speed up of about 2-3 orders of magnitude. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49011917/4045774

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be generating the combinations mesh out of `x,y,z`, then using [`kd-tree based quick nearest-neighbor lookup`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.query.html) to trace back the indices. Thus, we would have one vectorized solution, like so -

```
from itertools import product
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree

# Form all combinations    
combs = np.array(list(product(x, y, z)))

# Find closest indices for each pt in coords
closest_idx = cKDTree(combs).query(coords, k=1)[1]

# Index into data array and retrieve the output
data2Out = data.ravel()[closest_idx]
```

**Memory saving**

We could optimize on memory by using the kd-tree computation on the three coordinates separately, thereby avoding the combinations creating part and hopefully boosting performance, like so -

```
I = cKDTree(x[:,None]).query(coords[:,[0]], k=1)[1]
J = cKDTree(y[:,None]).query(coords[:,[1]], k=1)[1]
K = cKDTree(z[:,None]).query(coords[:,[2]], k=1)[1]
data2Out = data[I,J,K]
```