# Can numpy.tensordot or ufunc replace this nested for loop?

Tags: python, numpy, loops, multidimensional-array, nested-loops

Note: I know this is very similar to [Use numpy.tensordot to replace a nested loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48996893/use-numpy-tensordot-to-replace-a-nested-loop) , only that the actual instance we are working on seemed different( I need quadratic form caclculation) and I wasn't smart enough to extrapolate the discussion there, hence asking this question.

Objective: Make computational speed faster by replacing for loops with matrix calculation or/and univeral functions.

The problem:

```
#Toy example
def A(a):
 return [[a,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,a**2]]

val = 0
for a in range(1,5):
 for x in [ [1,1,1], [2,2,2], [3,3,3] ]:
   val +=np.exp(-1* np.dot(np.dot(x,A(a)), x))  
print(val)
```

In actual implementation, I have  x as 9 dimensional vector ranging over 10**9 iterations, and a ranging over (50)**2 iterations, and it takes forever using this for loop? Any suggestions? I feel that tensordot seems most probable but I keep failing to get the result I want, hence asking.
Since I'm a real beginner, it would really help if you could write out a sample code that I could directly apply...
Thanks in advance.

Added: Upon further investigation, it does not necessarily seem to be that np.tensordot() is the fastest, so any solution other than for loops are welcome.(e.g. using np.einsum two times, combination of np.dot and np.einsum, etc. )
Thanks to @hpaulj , I know how to eliminate the z loop now , but I really want to solve the a loop as well...

Comment: `tensordot` works by reshaping and transposing the arrays so the problem reduces to a single `np.dot` call.

Comment: thanks for the remark. If you have time, could you leave the code for the tensordot case as well??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The

```
In [155]: a=1
     ...: val=0
In [156]: for x in [ [1,1,1], [2,2,2], [3,3,3] ]:
     ...:    val +=np.exp( np.dot(np.dot(x,A(a)), x))
     ...: 
In [157]: val
Out[157]: 1.5060973145850306e+35
```

part can be replaced with

```
In [158]: X = np.array([ [1,1,1], [2,2,2], [3,3,3] ])
In [159]: np.exp(np.einsum('ki,ij,kj->k',X,A(a),X)).sum()
Out[159]: 1.5060973145850306e+35
```

Comment: Thanks for fast reply! Do you know how to simultaneously eliminate the 'a' loop as well? In practice, that loop is also non trivial cost of time, and I thought you could somehow do it by np.tensordot or something??

Comment: Why are you fixated on tensordot?

Comment: i saw from a different source that numpy.dot was usually the fastest for large dimensions, and inferred that extended to tensordot as well... In any case, if there is an alternative to just simple for loop for 'a', i would be satisfied... Do you think it is infeasible to substitue the for loop for matrix calculation for my particular problem. Thanks anyway..

Comment: In you demo case there is only one `a` iteration.  If you can create a 3d array (m,3,3) for all possible `a`, the `einsum` could be extended to handle it.  When I tested `a=2`, the result was 10e50, swamping the much smaller `a=1` case.

Comment: @hapulj, your comments are always to the point. To reflect my actual problem, I changed my toy problem into (i)a with more than one iteration and (ii)included a negative sign in the exponential(I actually want to create a gaussian density..., hence a quadratic form ).                                                Could you kindly paste the test code for the extended einsum code( if tedious, you could only just paste the indexing part, which is the core part). Also, could you give me(an absolute beginner) advice on how you attained your depth and breadth of programming skills?

Comment: @hapulj, i think I figured how to do it; just create the array as you instructed and change the index to 'ki, lij, kj-> lk'. Thank you very much!